# Storing Large Objects of Data

Tags: ios

I've already found the answer to my question, but I'm still a bit confused on how to assemble it since I recently made the switch from Android to iOS development.

I wanted, for fun, to make an application which displays information about cars. Maybe I'm over thinking this task or trying to do something extremely daunting, but I can't figure out how to display a large collection of car models with information about their name, engine, etc and also a picture. I don't need an exact answer, but I would be thankful to be pointed in the right direction.

I was thinking about creating an xml file and then load all of these items using the Sq Lite.
Forgive me if I don't know what I'm talking about here.

Comment: "creating an xml file and then load all of these items using the Sq Lite" simply doesn't make sense. If you need to use a database, then use a database.

Comment: As I said before I don't know much about the topic, I've never populated a database before. But thanks, I guess your answer does make sense.

Comment: Start out with a static JSON located in the Bundle and a single table view. The JSON represents an Array of Cars. The table view displays an "overview" of the Car object. When this works, add a Detail View - resembling a "Master/Detail" approach. When this works, utilize Core Data ...

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` would be a started point to display a large collection of objects. Load them into an `NSArray` and then link the array to the table. You could also use `UICollectionView` if you prefer a tile layout to a table. There are millions of examples out there if you research how to implement these UI elements. You could load them from a file (if the list is static), load them from a server database, or save them to a local database (sqllite) if you needed to manipulate the data in a datastore.